# onClick "Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined'."

Tags: reactjs

```
const thing = () => {

let selectedPage = "hello"

const addCduPageButton = () => {
 return (
     <div>
      <button onClick={addCduPage(selectedPage)}>Add Page</button>
     </div>
    )
  }

const addCduPage = (value: string) => {
      console.log(value)
}

return(
    <div>
      {addCduPageButton}
    </div>
  )
}

export default thing;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJN1U.png

Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined'.

I am not understanding the issue with the onClick property of the button.

Comment: Likely you need `() => addCduPage(selectedPage)`. Hard to say w/o [mcve].

Comment: Please include the entire error message as text, not as a link to an image of text.

Comment: That said, the error message is clear, you can't assign something that is not a function (the expression `console.log("anything")`) to a property that expects a function (`onClick`).

Comment: I have updated the original post to include what i hope is a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Does the updated code seem to be more what you would expect? It doesn't seem to mater what I pass the `onClick` function it gives the same error.

Comment: Read the very first comment you received and compare it with what you have in your code.